# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com este pequeno problema no Laravel. O velho e bom, problema com o S que o Laravel poe no final. Ja pesquisei em inumeros foruns mas a solução dada não funciona.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'cautofacil.fornecedors' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from
>   `fornecedors`)

A TABELA no MySQL se CHAMA FORNECEDORES

```
>     <?php
> 
> use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint; use
> Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
> 
> class CreateFornecedoresTable extends Migration {
> 
>     
>     /**
>      * Run the migrations.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     
>     protected $table = "fornecedores";
>     
>     public function up() {
```

Ja dei protect na tabela e mesmo assim ele continua colocando o maledito S no fim. Alguém pode me dar uma luz por favor?

Muito Obrigado

Comment: Coloca o código do model.

Comment: Confere o nome da tabela com a do banco de dados pode estar errado

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é na **Migration** que faz isso, é no **Model**.

Abra o Model criado. Provavelmente, **Fornecedores.php**.

Coloca:

`protected $table = "fornecedores";`

E testa.

### Documentação

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'my_users';

}
```

Só funciona para tabelas nomeadas em inglês.

Answer (score 1):

Estava com o mesmo problema e resolveu!

```
class Annotation extends Model
{

   protected $table = "annotation";
   protected $fillable = ['titulo','message'];

}
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Amigos, comigo aconteceu esse problema porque tentei fazer um form request separado e chamando-o no lugar do request, enfim a model com database eloquent não aceitou pois ela é uma model de Autenticação por isso ela não vai aceitar um form request separado a validação terá que ser no próprio método. Ex:

```
public function update(UserRequest $request, $id)
{
  // Não vai aceitar
}
```

Terá que ser assim

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  // Vai aceitar
}
```